# How to reduce file size of animated GIF?

Tags: gif, image-quality, image-format, file-size

I'm making an animated GIF web ad that needs to be 40KB or under. Unfortunately the one I put together is much larger than that. How can I reduce the file size without losing too much image quality?

[image]
current size: 70KB

Answer (score 2):

### Photoshop

Reduce colors and increase `Lossy` until the file size matches your requirements.
You will be surprised how small your animated GIF will be.

For your file use those values, for instance:

`Save for Web…` > `GIF` Colors: 128; Lossy: 8%

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

- try using different software to compress it more
- reduce the color palette to the absolute minimum
- reduce the number of transitions (try 2 transitions instead of 3)
- remove the background pattern (GIFs compress better with less horizontal changes in data). Maybe try a border instead.

Comment: Great, thank you for the advice! I didn't realize that horizontal elements can have such an impact on the file size.

Comment: Yep, GIFs use LZW compression and apply it on a row-by-row basis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Image_coding